# mysql queries on two foreign keys referencing the same table

Tags: mysql

I am new to Stack Overflow and a newbie in Mysql. This is my first time to ask here.

I am having a hard time on two different columns on Table 'Client':
Service Address Code as Area_Code 
Billing Address Code as BillAreaCode
-- both are foreign keys referencing to Table `Area_Codes`

It has no problems showing the rows when the values of Area_Code and BillAreaCode is the same. This is what I have on the table adapter:

```
SELECT * FROM  subscriber INNER JOIN
         area_codes ON subscriber.Area_Code = area_codes.Area_Code JOIN
         area_codes ON subscriber.BillAreaCode = area_codes.Area_Code
```

A lot of thanks for those who could help :)

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Am I missing something on the syntax? Because not all the records are showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your tables you want to join an alias, then use this alias to specify the correct (same) table. Also, and more importantly, never use `SELECT *`, specially in this case. Specify the columns you want to read and give them aliases as well since you try to read the same columns twice from the `area_codes` table which would result in duplicate column names in the result set.

Comment: so in this case, how do I put the alias syntax?

Comment: The syntax is the same, it's `AS new_name` as described on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html (see the definition of `table_factor`) and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#idm140409147673680